# Reduce a collection to a single object of another type with streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I found no solution yet for reducing a collection of one type (e.g. `MyData`) to one object of another type (e.g. `MyResult`) using Java streams.

```
@Test
public void streams() {
    List<MyData> collection = Arrays.asList(
            new MyData("1", "cool"), 
            new MyData("2", "green"),
            new MyData("3", "night"));

    // How reduce the collection with streams?
    MyResult result = new MyResult();
    collection.stream().forEach((e) -> {
        if (e.key.equals("2")) {
            result.color = e.value;
        }
    });

    MyResult expectedResult = new MyResult();
    expectedResult.color = "green";
    assertThat(result).isEqualTo(expectedResult);
}

public static class MyData {
    public String key;
    public String value;

    public MyData(String key, String value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }
}

public static class MyResult {
    public String color;
    public String material;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) {
            return true;
        }
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        MyResult myResult = (MyResult) o;
        return Objects.equals(this.color, myResult.color) &&
                Objects.equals(this.material, myResult.material);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(this.color, this.material);
    }
}
```

Is there a solution using some kind of reduce or fold?

Comment: You just want to find a data item with key "2"? Where would the resulting `MyResult` get its `material` from?

Comment: `collection.stream().filter(e -> e.key.equals("2").findFirst().map(e -> { result.color = e.value; })`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Did you mean :

```
collection.stream()
        .filter(e -> e.key.equals("2"))
        .findFirst()
        .orElse(null);//Or any default value
```

You can even throw an exception :

```
collection.stream()
        .filter(e -> e.key.equals("2"))
        .findFirst()
        .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("No data found"));
```

Comment: It’s best not to encourage people to write `new Exception`.  IllegalArgumentException or IllegalStateException would be much better.

Comment: @YCF_L Thanks. My example is simplified. I have to take more than one element from the stream in real life.

Comment: @sschmeck I don't get you! but if you want to get more than one you can use `List<MyData> result = collection.stream().filter(e -> e.key.equals("2")).collect(toList());` this will return a list of MyData, is that what you mean?

Comment: "You can even throw an exception :". even the first example will throw a `NullPointerException` if there is no value present as you're passing `null` to `orElseGet`. the java doc for [orElseGet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElseGet-java.util.function.Supplier-) states _Throws:
NullPointerException - if value is not present and other is null_. `other` being the `null` you've passed into `orElseGet`. did you mean to use `orElse`?.

Comment: @Aominè good catch Thank you for the information, I fix it ;)

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to convert a list of some type to another based on a condition ?

```
MyResult result = new MyResult();
        List<MyResult> resultList = collection.stream().filter(e -> e.key.equals("2")).map(e -> {
            MyResult resultTemp = new MyResult();
            result.color = e.value;
            return result;
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

try this

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution using [`Collector.of()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html).

```
Collector<MyData, MyResult, MyResult> myCollector = Collector.of(
        () -> new MyResult(),
        (a, e) -> {
            if (e.key.equals("2")) {
                a.color = e.value;
            }
        },
        (a1, a2) -> null, // Not used, therefore not working scaffold
        a -> a
);
MyResult result = collection.stream().collect(myCollector);
```

After all it doesn't feel idiomatically.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can just first find the element you're looking for

```
Optional<MyData> found = stream.filter(data -> data.key == 2).findFirst();
```

then map it to your result

```
Optional<MyResult> result = found.map(data -> { 
        MyResult r = new MyResult(); 
        r.color = data.color; 
        return r; 
});
```

Now you have an `Optional` that is empty if the original stream didn't contain an item with key 2, and a matching `MyResult` otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

The operation you're looking for is Map. Take a read through the Stream docs for some more details: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html

Here is a code snippet for mapping your List of MyData objects into a List of MyResult objects.

```
    List<MyResult> collect = collection.stream().map(myData -> {
        MyResult myResult = new MyResult();
        myResult.color = myData.value;
        return myResult;
    }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If you want to find just a single value simply add a filter transformation before the Map transformation.

```
    List<MyResult> collect = collection.stream()
            .filter(myData -> "2".equals(myData.key))
            .map(myData -> {
                MyResult myResult = new MyResult();
                myResult.color = myData.value;
                return myResult;
            }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```